# Implementing Laugerre's method in python

Tags: python, math, polynomials

I'm writing a python module for mathematics, and I've tried to create a basic implementation
of Laguerre's Method, without using external libraries such as numpy or scipy.

Laguerre's method is an algorithm for finding roots of polynomials ( i.e : intersection with the x axis ) , and it's further elaborated in
Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre%27s_method

Here is what I came up with:

```py
def laguerre_method(f_0: Callable, f_1: Callable, f_2: Callable, x0: float, n: float, epsilon: float = 0.00001):
    xk = x0
    while abs(f_0(xk)) > epsilon:
        G = f_1(xk) / f_0(xk)
        H = G ** 2 - f_2(xk) / f_0(xk)
        root = cmath.sqrt((n - 1) * (n * H - G ** 2))
        d = max(abs(G + root), abs(G - root))
        a = n / d
        xk -= a
    return xk
```

f_0 is the original function, f_1 is its derivative, and f_2 is the second derivative. 
x0 is a guess we start from. 
 Epsilon represents how close to 0 the y value of a point should be, to be considered a root.

n represents the power of the polynomial, i.e, for x^3 + 3x + 5, the power is 3.

For some reason, the method works as expected when the initial value ( x0 ) is positive, and even with small negative numbers, but it fails with bigger negative values, showing math domain error or OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large') , or ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

For example, let's define a function, its derivative, and its second derivative with lambdas:

```py
 f_0 = lambda n: 2 * n ** 3 - 5 * n ** 2 - 23 * n - 10
 f_1 = lambda n: 6 * n ** 2 - 10 * n - 23
 f_2 = lambda n: 12 * n - 10
```

The code works for these inputs:

```py
print(laguerre_method(f_0, f_1, f_2, 6, 3))
```

```py
print(laguerre_method(f_0, f_1, f_2, -1, 3))
```

And outputs approximately 5.0 and -2.0 respectively, which are the corresponding roots.

However it fails with this input for example:

```py
print(laguerre_method(f_0, f_1, f_2, -7, 3))
```

[image: Fails miserably for -7]

The algorithm is detailed in Wikipedia.

Keep in mind this is not the finished implementation, and that I know I've probably made a stupid error, so expect stupidity from my side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
d = max(abs(G + root), abs(G - root))
```

Should be:

```
d = max([G + root, G - root], key=abs)
```

Comment: Oh, guess i missed that ....thanks

Comment: Quoting Wikipedia, "the sign is chosen to give the denominator with the larger absolute value". In the first line, `abs` is applied to denominator, but it should only be used to choose the sign

Comment: Don't know why exactly but it works so thank you very much

Comment: `max(-7, -9)` would be `-7`,  `max(abs(-7), abs(-9))` would be `9` and `max([-7, -9], key=abs)` would be `-9` ("take the original value which has the maximal absolute value").

Comment: Ohhhhh I understand now